# VBA Macro Excel How to update master file

Tags: excel, vba

I want to update a master file which has the columns of part, customer code ,customer name, maker, department and status from a report.

The report has the same columns as the master file.
Sometimes the status column is changed for the existing part such as from stage1 to stage2.
Sometimes new parts are added to the report and in that case, I need to add the new ones if they do not exit in the master file.

I have created a formula in the report whether a part needs to be added to the master file or not.
The formula returns "Add" or blank.

Here's the macro I have created.

```
Sub updateMasterFile()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, lr As Long
Dim rFiltered As Range
Dim filter_rng_src As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report") 
.Activate
lr = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With .ListObjects("Report")
         .Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Add"
    End With
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rFiltered = .Range("Report").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If rFiltered Is Nothing Then
        .Activate
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Else
        Set filter_rng_src = .Range("F4:L" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Range("G4:L" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Call GetParts(filter_rng_, lr)
        'On Error GoTo eh
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").ListObjects("MasterTable").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If
    
End With


Sub GetParts(filter_rng_src As Range, lr As Long)

Dim wbMaster As Workbook
Dim lrMaster As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open("fileLocation")

lrMaster = wbMaster.Sheets("Master").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lrMaster
 For Each r In filter_rng_src 
   'Existing check
    If wbMaster.Sheets("Master").Cells(i, 7) = r.Value Then
        ' QUESTION ///I do not know how to get the value of the status column from the report. 
        ' QUESTION ///How do I access to a column of filter_rng_src??

    Else 
    ' If not exist
            With wbMaster
                Dim lrMaster2 As Long
                .Activate
                With .Sheets("Master")
                 'get the values from the filtered range 
                 ' and add it to the bottom of the table of the master file.
                  'Question /// How do I get only the values of filter_rng_src which does not exist in the master file??

              End With
            End With
   Next r
 Next i
End Sub
```

How do I get the value of the part information from the report to master file?

Comment: Sidenote: Try change these two lines `For i = 2 To lrMaster` and  `For Each r In filter_rng_src ` and after `Next i` a `Next r` is missing.

Comment: @Blackcat what do I change them?

Comment: Want to search each element of `filter_rng_src` in `lrMaster` aren't you? Generally the master has much more items than the lookup range. And therefore it is shorter int time. And if an equality is found exit for.

Comment: @Blackcat I see, that's right. Actually that's what I was concerned about. The Master has over 700 records and the number of records will keep increasing. Thank you so much. I have another question. Is it possible to access to a column of `r`? Because `filter_rng_src ` has multiple columns and I want to get one of the columns' value to when the criteria meets in the if statement.

Comment: Yes. For example `a=range("A1:A20").Columns(1)` returns a two dimensional array like a(row,column), row goes 1 to 20 and column=1